# Solving environment: Failed with initial solver frozen when installing fenics

Tags: python

I am trying to install fenics. In Ubuntu, install anaconda3, then open jupyter notebook, then type in the below commands according to website.

https://fenicsproject.org/download/

```
!conda config --add channels conda-forge
!conda install fenics
```

But I still got an error of

Solving environment: Failed with initial solver frozen when installing fenics

I have already tried

```
conda update --all
```

and I still got same error.

One thing I noticed that, after opening jupyter notebook, I saw red text error of

```
Start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start "file:///home/test/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-23 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Could anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try running this line of code to solve the issue.

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Pretty sure this changes the path back to BASH.

Hope I helped you!